# I am unable to save .py files to the current working directory in Python

Tags: python

I have prepared the following script prepared to set my current working directory in Python:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
if os.getcwd() !="D:\Documents\Tech Stuff\Python\Files":
    os.chdir("D:\Documents\Tech Stuff\Python\Files")
print (os.getcwd())
```

After executing a script via IDLE I created a new python file and clicked on 'Save as'. I still see the default Python window in C:\Program Files open and not the directory mentioned above.

Can anybody explain why I am not able to set the Current Working directory properly and also mention a workaround for the same?

I am using Python version  3.51.

Comment: are you aware that backslashes in python strings are treated as escape characters?

Comment: Try changing all '\' to '\\' first?

Comment: I did that. It's not working. Is there any other way?

Comment: try : `os.chdir(r"D:\Documents\Tech Stuff\Python\Files\")` if this is a valid directory(Maybe you try writing a RO(read only) file system !).

Comment: Not working either. @dsgdfg

Comment: like this : `path=r"D:\Documents\Tech Stuff\Python\Files"` and write file procedure`_file=open(path +r"\filename.etc", "w")`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Executing that script from an editor or IDE does _not_ change the editor's or IDE's working directory!  Is the `print()` at the end print `D:\Documents\Tech Stuff\Python\Files`? If yes, then it's working correctly by changing that script's process working directory, which is all you should expect from it.